# What is text after colon in process name in ps

Tags: linux

What is the text after colon in a process name in the ps listing below? I know what the text means but I am looking for where that text is specified in a process.

```
6965 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process nginx
8213 ?        S      0:01  \_ nginx: worker process
8214 ?        S      0:01  \_ nginx: worker process
8215 ?        S      0:01  \_ nginx: worker process
8216 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
```

Comment: try asking at [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) sub-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [prctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html), PR_SET_NAME is the right system call you're looking for.

Copied from that page:

> ```
>    PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)
>           Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the
>           location pointed to by (char *) arg2.  The name can be up to
>           16 bytes long, and should be null-terminated if it contains
>           fewer bytes.  This is the same attribute that can be set via
>           pthread_setname_np(3) and retrieved using
>           pthread_getname_np(3).  The attribute is likewise accessible
>           via /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm, where tid is the name of the
>           calling thread.
> ```

Comment: or the more traditional `setproctitle`

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be used to name a thread but it appears to be used in naming processes too (their main thread) as above. Thanks.